# Происхождение слова "двоюродный"

Tags: этимология

Брусникин, он же Акунин, в своем романе "Девятный спас" устами одного из героев объясняет:"Двоюродный - вдвойне родной". Насколько верно такое объяснение для описываемой эпохи (время Петра I)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не читал, но предполагаю, что герой просто каламбурит. Ни при Петре, ни когда-либо ещё такого смысла в понятие "двоюродный"  не вкладывалось, ни по смыслу (это очевидно), ни, так сказать, этимологически. Двоюродный - это вторая степень родства, "наполовину родной".

Всё, что приходит на память, это сеймейные отношения Древней Руси, когда дядья (братья наследодателя) были приоритетными наследниками перед племянниками (детьми наследодателя). Т.е. как бы двоюродный родственник имел более близкое родство по отношению к родному. Но к самому термину "двоюродный" это никак не могло иметь отношения.

Comment: Спасибо...